# Wordpress sage bootstrap not working

Tags: wordpress, npm, wordpress-theming, yarnpkg

I have setup a fresh wordpress installation with bedrock and I want to build a theme using the sage workflow.

I've installed everything correctly and I've run a `yarn build` successfully.

Now when I try something very simple in my body like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <row>
        <div class="col-md-4">col1</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">col2</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">col3</div>
    </row>
</div>
```

It doesn't actually seem to be working, I just get 3 divs below each other instead of in the bootstrap grid.

When I inspect the element I see the correct css classes and stuff.

During my setup of sage I've selected to load in Bootstrap so I am not sure why it's not working.

```
 Which framework would you like to load? [Bootstrap]:
  [0] None
  [1] Bootstrap
  [2] Bulma
  [3] Foundation
  [4] Tachyons
 > 1

 Are you sure you want to overwrite the following files?
 - scripts/autoload/_bootstrap.js
 - styles/autoload/_bootstrap.scss
 - styles/common/_variables.scss
 - styles/components/_comments.scss
 - styles/components/_forms.scss
 - styles/components/_wp-classes.scss
 - styles/layouts/_header.scss

 (yes/no) [no]:
 > yes

Done.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be like this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">col1</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">col2</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">col3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

please make sure bootstrap.css is loading in source code.

Comment: This seems to be working but when I try to make a nav like this: https://codepen.io/Ij888/pen/oWoNep it always shows the collapsed nav on all screen sizes I don't know why since both the bootstrap css and js are loaded in the source code

Comment: Have you the  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">` in your head ? Try basic responsive with cols to see if they works.